# Rails datetime format "dd/mm/yyyy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I receive dates like `"14/04/17 07:00"`

I want to get only the date like this: `14/04/2017`

And only the hour `07:00`

I tried this way, BTW I know it's for US time, it render me `17/04/10`

```
DateTime.parse(datetime).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Humm I can't find anywhere how to do this?

Thanks for your help

## EDIT

with the suggestion:

`my_date = DateTime.parse(datetime).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`

If I do in my terminal:

```
[1] pry(main)> O = Onduleur.last
  Onduleur Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "onduleurs".* FROM "onduleurs" ORDER BY "onduleurs"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Onduleur:0x007fa6b70186e0
 id: 144,
 identifier: 2,
 datetime: "11/04/17 23:00",
 energy: 0,
 created_at: Wed, 12 Apr 2017 15:17:04 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 12 Apr 2017 15:17:04 UTC +00:00>
[2] pry(main)> my_date = DateTime.parse(O.datetime).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
=> "17/04/2011"
[3] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Did you read the docummentation about [strftime](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) ?

Comment: If you just need string results, why not splitting the input string with the split method ?

Comment: I read about `strftime` but it always return the US date format... I've been told to use `strptime`but I don't manage either

Comment: yes spliting could work... true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For reading you can use `strptime` and specify the format:**

```
datetime = "14/04/17 07:00"
DateTime.strptime(datetime, "%d/%m/%y %R")
=> Wed, 14 Apr 0017 07:00:00 +0000
```

Explanation

```
%d - Day of the month, zero-padded (01..31)
%m - Month of the year, zero-padded (01..12)
%y - year % 100 (00..99)
%R - 24-hour time (%H:%M)
```

**For getting the date you can transform DateTime objects to Date objects using `to_date` or use `.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")` directly on DateTime to get String.**

```
[47] pry(main)> a
=> Fri, 14 Apr 2017 07:00:00 +0000
[48] pry(main)> a.to_date
=> Fri, 14 Apr 2017
[49] pry(main)> a.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
=> "14/04/2017"
[50] pry(main)> a.strftime("%R")
=> "07:00"
```

Full docs [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strptime/class). Also a full list of format directives is available on [strftime docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Comment: In the console it returns `Sun, 11 Apr 0017 23:00:00 +0000`  `0017`instead of `2017`

Comment: have a try now @Nelly

Answer (score 0):

You can set to variables with the desire data

```
datetime = "2017-04-12 10:30:14"

my_date = DateTime.parse(datetime).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
my_hour = DateTime.parse(datetime).strftime("%H:%M")

puts my_date
puts my_hour
```

Output:

> 12/04/2017
>   10:30

**EDIT:**

If you have this format date (**11/04/2017 23:00**), you can try with `.to_time` method

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'

datetime2 = "11/04/2017 23:00".to_time

my_date2 = datetime2.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
my_hour2 = datetime2.strftime("%H:%M")

puts my_date2
puts my_hour2
```

Comment: my datetime is not formated like this `"2017-04-12 10:30:14"` but like this `"11/04/17 23:00"`that's why it doesn't work :(